# Test failing with Error while committing the transaction when using @NotBlank annotation

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, validation, exception

Here's the entity that contains the @NotBlank annotation:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
//...

@Entity(name = "funds")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE funds SET deleted_at = now() WHERE id = ?")
@Where(clause = "deleted_at is null")
public class Fund implements Serializable {

  @Column(nullable = false)
  @NotBlank(message = "Name is mandatory")
  private String name;

  ...
```

Here's my rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/funds")
public class FundController
{
    @Autowired
    private FundRepository fundRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public @ResponseBody Fund create(
        @RequestParam("name") String name,
        @RequestParam(value = "amount", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Double amount,
        @RequestParam("currency") Integer currencyId,
        Principal principal) {

        Fund fund = new Fund(name, amount);
        //...
        return fundRepository.save(fund);
    }

    //...

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public String handleValidationExceptions(ConstraintViolationException e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
```

Here's the test for the field validator:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class FundsControllerTest extends ControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void testCreateFund_whenFieldsInValid_thenBadRequest() throws Exception {

        String accessToken = getAccessToken(USER_USERNAME, USER_PASSWORD);

        mockMvc.perform(
            post("/funds/create")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
                .param("name", "") // empty 
                .param("amount", "1000")
                .param("currency", currency.getId().toString())
            ).andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }
```

However, I'm seeing the following error:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 12.611 s <<< FAILURE! - in biz.martyn.budget.FundsControllerTest
[ERROR] testCreateFund_whenFieldsInValid_thenBadRequest(biz.martyn.budget.FundsControllerTest)  Time elapsed: 1.533 s  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
        at biz.martyn.budget.FundsControllerTest.testCreateFund_whenFieldsInValid_thenBadRequest(FundsControllerTest.java:109)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
        at biz.martyn.budget.FundsControllerTest.testCreateFund_whenFieldsInValid_thenBadRequest(FundsControllerTest.java:109)
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
        at biz.martyn.budget.FundsControllerTest.testCreateFund_whenFieldsInValid_thenBadRequest(FundsControllerTest.java:109)
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: 
Validation failed for classes [biz.martyn.budget.fund.Fund] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be blank', propertyPath=name, rootBeanClass=class biz.martyn.budget.fund.Fund, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank.message}'}
]
        at biz.martyn.budget.FundsControllerTest.testCreateFund_whenFieldsInValid_thenBadRequest(FundsControllerTest.java:109)
```

If I remove the @NotBlank annotation then the test still fails, but not from an exception just because it fails the assertion (expecting bad request). So seems an issue with that annotation. Anythign I've missed?

Comment: `@NotBlank` means `name` must not contain the empty String. But you enter an empty String so you get an exception. I'm not sure why you would expect anything else.

Comment: Well I wouldn't expect to get an unhandled exception. I'd expect to get a 4xx response. Why would it be attempting to insert into the database when a field is not valid?

Comment: Ok, so this is more about exception translation and handling.

Comment: These might be helpful: https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring https://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/ https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_bean_validation_options

Comment: Why is it attempting to update the database when it should not be validating? The @NotBlank is being ignored, that's what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: Is that the case? Please show the full stack trace.

Comment: Actually, I perhaps am mistaken that it's ignoring it. It seems to throw a ConstraintViolationException which is triggering a RollbackException and TransactionSystemException further up the stack. I've tried to catch the ConstraintViolationException in the controller (see updated code) but it's not picking it up from that. Just the same errors when the test is run. I'm not sure I want to catch the RollbackException and TransactionSystemException as those could be triggered I'm guessing from things other than Hibernate validation errors as they are in this case.